# Rstudio - keybord shortcut for multiple replacement in source window

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I know it is possible to replace multiple items simultaneously in R. I have this sequence of commands:

[image]

How can I modify all the items that are in a box by only using the keyboard? I am aware of the find function and Keyboard Shortcuts Help, but that's not what I am looking for.

Maybe someone can suggest a nice summary of similar tricks and shortcuts? I have looked briefly on youtube, with no satisfactory findings.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - Rename in scope
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> - Keyboard Shortcut Quick Reference